# Piwik iframe displaying multiple tab instead of showing analytics of website

Tags: php, html, magento, matomo

I have installed piwik in ubuntu and then i have installed Piwik Ecommerce from magento connect. Piwik is running on sever, but piwik iframe is not displaying any results in magento backend.

`Reports->PiwikIframe` displaying multiple tabs, and not giving any information. I have also added the following line in `config/config.ini.php` under general tab:

> enable_framed_pages=1

Comment: added a little markup & piwik tag